# Airflow elasticsearch hook

Tags: python, elasticsearch, airflow, hook

I need help with elasticsearch hook on airflow.

I've imported the following:

```
from airflow.providers.elasticsearch.hooks.elasticsearch import ElasticsearchHook
```

and run the command to search an index:

```
elastic_hook = ElasticsearchHook(elasticsearch_conn_id = 'ELK')

elastic_conn = elastic_hook.get_conn()

res = elastic_conn.search(index=es_index,

size = 10000,

from_= 0,

request_timeout=1000,

body = body, scroll='2m', )
```

But I'm getting an error that "connection object has no attribute search".
I've tried running dir command on the hook object and got the following:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_generate_insert_sql', '_serialize_cell', '_set_context', 'bulk_dump', 'bulk_load', 'conn_name_attr', 'conn_type', 'connection', 'connector', 'default_conn_name', 'elasticsearch_conn_id', 'get_autocommit', 'get_conn', 'get_connection', 'get_connections', 'get_cursor', 'get_first', 'get_hook', 'get_pandas_df', 'get_records', 'get_sqlalchemy_engine', 'get_uri', 'hook_name', 'insert_rows', 'log', 'run', 'schema', 'set_autocommit', 'supports_autocommit']
```

Yet I have no idea how to transform my search command (that follows a scroll right after) with one of this functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For [`apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch>=4.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch/) :

There is `ElasticsearchPythonHook` which expose the `search` endpoint from Elasticsearch Python SDK. It was added by [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24895)
Example usage:

```
def use_elasticsearch_hook():
    es_hook = ElasticsearchPythonHook(hosts=["http://localhost:9200"])
    query = {"query": {"match_all": {}}}
    result = es_hook.search(query=query)
    print(result)
    return True
```

For [`apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch<4.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-elasticsearch/) :

There is no `search` function in the hook. You can only use SQL to interact with Elasticsearch. The hook has [get_conn](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/32c63626845b9885c2349190ba9e44691007bbdb/airflow/providers/elasticsearch/hooks/elasticsearch.py#L47) & [get_uri](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/32c63626845b9885c2349190ba9e44691007bbdb/airflow/providers/elasticsearch/hooks/elasticsearch.py#L70) functions. Since the hook inherits from `DbApiHook` all of its functions are also available. You can use the [tests](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a781093bdbc8eda7ba22d9971351897c6bc1b101/tests/providers/elasticsearch/hooks/test_elasticsearch.py#L47) as example how to use it.
Alternatively you can install the elasticsearch SDK and interact with it directly by creating a custom hook.

Comment: The link for "tests" is broken.
Anyway thanks for that, much appreciated.
I just need an example of using hook with elastic, not with SQL code but with json query and to implement scroll as well.

Comment: The implementation of the hook is with SQL structure not with HTTP. If you need it with HTTP you will need to create a custom hook yourself or use a 3rd party code like https://github.com/brucehsu/airflow-elasticsearch-toolkit/blob/master/hooks/elastic_hook.py

Comment: @EranH If still needed please see my edited answer. Now the search endpoint is supported natively.